# Can we run apache on a non-root account?

Tags: security, non-root-user, apache-httpd

Apache is started by the root user, then switches to the user defined by the User directive; is there any chance where we can change this default behavior? Apache should start using a non-root account and then switch to the user defined by the User directive.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think in terms of apache  hardening this would be good. Also I need to know if this is possible, if we create a non-root user which has privileges to bind to ports 80,443 and apache should start under this non-root user

Comment: Yeah [you can definitely do it](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NonRootPortBinding) I'm just skeptical you're going to get any security benefit from it. The only purpose of starting as root is to bind to lower end port numbers after which it's just an artifact and shouldn't have any impact on your level of vulnerability at all.

Comment: So there would be no security benefit from this ?

Comment: No because the unprivileged user is the only one actually communicating over the network. The root user is just there for the first part. The root user program sticks around but it's not communicating outside the server.

Comment: Only the `root` user has privileges to open listening TCP network sockets on ports below 1000, which is why the service needs to bootstrap as `root`:  80 < 1000.  So theoretically you could run the service without involving the superuser, but only if you don't intend to be listening for traffic on the standard HTTP/HTTPS ports.

Comment: Sure you can, it's very common. What distribution are you using, that doesn't run Apache as a dedicated user by default?

Comment: @DopeGhoti The usual way to do it is that Apache starts as root, binds port 80, and then drops privileges. On Linux, instead of starting as root, it may start with the appropriate capability (I think Fedora does it these days but not Debian).

Comment: Yeah, Apache can _run_ as a separate user like `apache` or `www` (and indeed should!), but AFAIK only root can bind to low ports, which is why we have this whole start-as-root-and-deescelate dance in the first place.